# How to absalutely fully change terminal prompt to color

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

its mind bogglingly supprising how hard it is to TOTALLY change terminal prompt graphic featurs.... Like

```
PS1
```

Or in my case color features.... I have edited /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc and /root/.bashrc

For those who want a quick solution i recommend just editing this file

```
~/.bashrc
```

So type this command and reAd through the file

```
pico ~/.bashrc
```

that file you just edited gets loaded every login. Or if you type the command "source ~/.bashrc" or ". ~/.bashrc"

Ok so after i did all that.... I STILL dont fully get color....

```
read test; $test
```

I type ls and get no color...

Or another example

```
Lol=ls
$Lol
```

Or another example, when i make an alias command

```
alias ls="ls -a"
```

No color

the problem is command is being executed by shell, and NOT by me..?

How can i just change the output to color... Always ^.^ im guessing i can just copy paste that section about fancy color from .bashrc somewhere. But i swear.... Why is this so hard... On my ipad i could just smash my face and it would work. Or on microsoft i click ENABLE COLOR for cmd.exe ^.^

I really really really mean ALWAYS, i want to go program cool stuf f but customizing my terminal is hard O.o and i program in the terminal..... I have too.... Because

90% of what i program is in perl, and i grew up sshing into servers and writing perl with emacs or pico or vi. So when i code i want to code in my terminal, and i want the output in color. Its something i never had the option of before.

I have never owned linux until now....

Comment: What gave you the idea that the color of your prompt has anything to do with the color of your `ls` output? Read `man ls` and search for "color".

Comment: A bit more focused approach to the several mentioned points of disappointment would surely help. If you could just narrow your question down a bit (and save the other inconveniences for asking them seperately) you would definitely enhance your chance on a high quality answer.

Answer (score 2):

No worries mate, don't panic. You are a programmer and you have done fantastic things so flipping out over something quite simple is not you, right ?

So you left windows for linux, just like you could exchange your car with automatic gearbox for a mammoth transporter with 40 wheels and a 28 speed gearshift and now you are not feeling comfortable with the controls because it is not your beloved *Holden Barina*, right ?

That is okay, let's get down to it.

***"the problem is command is being executed by shell, and NOT by me..?"***

It always is, mate, it always is. On any system, even on windows.

***"How can i just change the output to color... Always"***

If you want *Always* colors, just change the color of your terminal like, yellow letters on a black screen...it's easy: Just go to the *preferences* of your terminal-emulator.

besides that...a lot of programs can be set to color output. We don't do that in the registry... no way!...we won't have that. We just put an entry in **.bashrc**, an *alias*... much easier than fooling around in the registry and *break the whole system*

***"Why is this so hard"***

Naaaah...You are kidding yourself mate, it is easy as kindergarten. You just have to get used to your new found power. No automatic gearbox remember ?

***"On my ipad i could just smash my face and it would work."***

Strange head you have, mate. If I smash my face on an iPad, it usually breaks.

***"Or on microsoft i click ENABLE COLOR for cmd.exe"***

Yeah..that is microsoft logic for you, mate. I always had to type "**cmd**" for *cmd.exe* .
Anyway, I have color all the time *automagically*.

***"i want to go program cool stuf"***

I am glad for you, mate. Programming is a blessing

***"but customizing my terminal is hard O.o and i program in the terminal"***

Awww...come on mate, you don't want to do that...you might want at least to use an *editor* but because you are from windows you're probably used to program on a GUI IDE  right ? So back off the commandline and use **geany** , a full blown GUI IDE which has a lot of colors to tinker around with. When you grow up a bit with the system you can try doing terminal stuff.

***"90% of what i program is in perl, and i grew up sshing into servers and writing perl with emacs or pico or vi. So when i code i want to code in my terminal, and i want the output in color. Its something i never had the option of before."***

I think you are exaggerating a bit, mate. **Nano** is *full color*, **mc** is *full color*, **emacs** is *full color*, **vi** is *full color*, even **htop** is *full color*. Ubuntu's terminal and commandline-tools are set to *full color* **out of the box**. So tell me:

*What did you do to your system that you don't have any color anymore? How did you break it ?*